# Laptop hardware causing Linux screen brightness to misbehave

Tags: linux, laptop, lcd, brightness

I have Linux Lite installed (after using Lubuntu for a couple of years) on my 10 yr old Laptop (Sony Vaio).
The problem started from Lubuntu and I removed it in vain, since the problem has not resolved with the new distro.

My screen starts flickering abruptly.

Initially I thought (later proved correct) that my screen flickered or stopped flickering while changing angles of my laptop display. Maybe a loose connection. Not confident in hardware repair, I have tried my hand at every command to correct screen brightness - xbacklight, changing backlight and acpi settings, bash.rc, grub command line options - everything.
At certain screen angles, reducing brightness by software slider increases flickering, and at other angles it just ignores brightness slider and sets itself at max brightness. Since 2012 I have used "sudo tee | echo backlight/brightness" command successfully.

Does this seem like a hardware bug?

Comment: I assume you are not using the 5.19.12 Linux kernel?

Comment: Add the kernel version in use (`uname -r`) and give it a check to the video drivers. To rule out the hardware failure explanation you may prepare a boot-able usb with another Linux flavor/kernel+drivers... (Maybe it can be enough to boot with the _rescue mode_, see [e.g. here](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/) method 2, just when in the text mode with the window, change the screen angles: no problems probably no hardware problems related with the screen... ).